# How to pass only one side of either as a parameter Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, parameter-passing, either

One of my functions returns either:

```
parse :: Int -> String -> Either String JsonLikeValue
```

And other takes `JsonLikeValue` as a parameter:

```
convert :: Int -> JsonLikeValue -> Either InvalidState To
```

`JsonLikeValue` is custom data type:

```
data JsonLikeValue = JLString String | JLInt Int | JLArray [JsonLikeValue] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

And when I call:

```
convert num (parse size message)
```

it gives following:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘JsonLikeValue’
                  with actual type ‘Either String JsonLikeValue’
```

How can this be avoided and only right side be passed as argument?
Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** solution marked as answer is very helpful since it takes into consideration all possible outcomes, and as I'm not an expert but still, looks more professional, so it is very important to take a look at it.

But what was enough to solve the required extraction was:

```
extractValue :: Either String JsonLikeValue -> JsonLikeValue
extractValue a = case a of
        Left e -> JLArray []
        Right r -> r
```

where in case of `Right` it returns only value, and in case of `Left` it returns something of required data type. Note that this only works if you're 100% sure that argument will return `Right` value. Otherwise, check answer below.

Another good notice in comments is to use `fromRight` from `Data.Either`

Comment: What do you want to return in case `parse size message` returns a `Left ...`.

Comment: Only when `parse size message` returns right it should be called, so it is not important what happens when `left` value is returned in my case. Any possible case would suit me, even simple "error" `string`

Comment: THe problem is what your expression should *return*. What should be the *result* of some expression like `convert num (parse size message)`. If `parse` returns `Left "Foo"`, it can not return an `Either InvalidState`, since `InvalidState` is not a `String`.

Comment: I see what you're trying to ask, but it's not determined what should be returned in that case, lets then say, that instead of `parse size message` only argument for `JsonLikeValue` that will be passed to `convert` is `expectedParse :: Either String JsonLikeValue`
 `expectedParse = Right $ some JsonLikeValue` and it never can be left, that's what's needed here

Comment: Because only `InvalidState`s are determined by the content of JsonLikeValue passed and not the result of either

Comment: well the output can be something like `Either (Either String InvalidState) JsonLikeValue`, so then we use an `Either` for the "error"` to make a distinction between the two errors.

Comment: And in this case how can `expectedParse` be passed as an argument to the function?

Comment: If you are sure `parse` is called when returning `Right ...`, then you can use `fromRight` fom `Data.Either`, changing your function to `convert num . fromRight <some default value> $ (parse size message)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that we need to return something in case the `parse` value returns a `Left …` value. We can for example make a function that combines the two "errors" with:

```
myfunction :: Int -> Int -> String -> Either (Either String InvalidState) To
myfunction = …
```

We can make use of pattern matching to unpack the value in case of a `Right` and then use the `convert` function, like:

```
myfunction :: Int -> Int -> String -> Either (Either String InvalidState) To
myfunction size num message = go (parse size message)
    where go (Left e) = Left (Left e)
          go (Right jlv) = pp (convert num jlv)
          pp (Left e) = Left (Right e)
          pp (Right r) = Right r
```

Here `go` thus inspects the result of the `parse size message` value, and in case it is a `Left e`, we return `Left (Left e)`. If it is a `Right jlv` (with `jlv` the `JsonLikeValue` wrapped in it), we thus call `convert num jlv`.

We still need to post-process the result with the `pp` function. The `convert num jlv` will have type `Either InvalidState To`, and we need to convert it to an `Either (Either String InvalidState) To`. We do that by converting a `Left e` to a `Left (Right e)`, and a `Right r` to a `Right r`. Note that the `Right` in the body is a data constructor of the `Either (Either String InvalidState) To` type, wheras the `Right` in the head is a data constructor of the `Either InvalidState To`, so the two are not the same.